# splitting R G B image and using blob detection to detect red shapes in Open cv and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, split, computer-vision, blob

I am using open CV and C++. I need to detect some circular red shaped points on a human face. I am using blob detection but it does not seem to work. I have split the image into red,blue and green but I think I am not getting the parameters right. Can anyone help please?
Here is my code http://pastebin.com/aGkUz3SG

Thanks

Comment: did you try `cv::namedWindow("r");cv::imshow("r",r);cv::waitKey(-1);` to test whether splitting was ok? looks right to me. There you might get an impression of whether your 'blobs' are really existent in the red channel.

Comment: sorry i am not able to post the picture. But here is a link to a picture which i am using. http://opticalengineering.spiedigitallibrary.org/data/Journals/OPTICE/22375/005508joe2.jpeg I am using the front face picture only, which contains red blobs. And yes i was able to split the photo into red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

your blob detector parameters don't fit. `.minArea` is much too big for the sample image you provided in the comment, since the blobs are very small. `.blobColor` is a problem since your red isn't perfect, see the image of the red channel I added at bottom. In addition, yellow is combination of red and green and might have a very high red value too. So `.filterByColor=false` might be better if you don't know the value of your red dots.

Here's the red channel, you will see that the red dots have a lower red value than the yellow dots and values are about the same as the values of the blue dots! In the third image, only one of the red dots is clearly visible to me as a human. On the fourth image, the dot next to the eye isn't really visible. All in all it looks like red channel isn't distinct enough to locate the red dots on human skin.

red channel:

[image]

I've tried HSV color space, but the hue value isn't really better, but in saturation channel at least all the dots are a bit visible:

hue:

[image]

saturation:

[image]

value:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for all the explanation!what colors would be best to use then?

Comment: maybe those colors will work, but not by just evaluating the "red channel". Try these links:
http://www.mathworks.de/products/image/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexfabric.html
 and 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/110269-color-segmentation-of-skin-markers-hsv-or-lab-how-to-choose-thresholds